# DATEPART IN SELECT CASE Not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The objective of the code below is to mutiple number of month by 2 when someone join the club after january 1st. When I run it, I get an error message.

My research on similar usage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197689/case-statement-with-datediff-and-datepart), shows my syntax is right. What am I doing wrong in my case?

> Error 102: Incorrect syntax near '<'.`

This is the complete code:

```
SELECT 
    ID, [HIREDate],
    CASE [HIREDate]
       WHEN 12 - (MONTH([HIREDate])) <> 0
          THEN 12 - (MONTH([HIREDate])) * 2
       ELSE 0
    END AS Days 
FROM 
    dbo.table 
WHERE
    column1 <> ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing the two "styles" of a `CASE` expression - try this:

```
SELECT 
    ID, [HIREDate],
    CASE 
       WHEN 12 - (MONTH([HIREDate])) <> 0
          THEN 12 - (MONTH([HIREDate])) * 2
       ELSE 0
    END AS Days 
FROM 
    dbo.table 
WHERE
    column1 <> ''
```

If you define a column just after the `CASE` like in your code:

```
CASE [HireDate]
```

then the `WHEN` clauses can **only** contain a **value** - not an expression:

```
CASE MONTH([HireDate])
   WHEN 1 THEN ....
   WHEN 2 THEN .....
```

If you need to have an **expression** in the `WHEN` clause, then you *cannot* put a column right after `CASE` - the `WHEN` clause needs to have all the information